# How to programmatically create a product review in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, review, ratings, product-review

I am trying to programmatically create a product review for an existing product in Magento 2.

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** Here i am giving u sample example on **creating review and rating** programmatically by using test script running at root folder of **magento2**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo "HELLO STACK EXCHANGE";


$productId=5;
$customerId=13; //for Guest user $customerId=Null;
$customerNickName='STACK EXCHANGE';
$reviewTitle='STACK EXCHANGE';
$reviewDetail='STACK EXCHANGE';
$StoreId=1;
$title='STACK EXCHANGE';


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_review = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\Review")
->setEntityPkValue($productId)    //product Id
->setStatusId(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_PENDING)// pending/approved
->setTitle($reviewTitle)
->setDetail($reviewDetail)
->setEntityId(1)
->setStoreId($StoreId)
->setStores(1)
->setCustomerId($customerId)//get dynamically here 
->setNickname($customerNickName)
->save();


echo "Review Has been saved ";

echo "/////FOR SAVING RATING /////////
     ///////////////////////////////";

/* 
 $_ratingOptions = array(
     1 => array(1 => 1,  2 => 2,  3 => 3,  4 => 4,  5 => 5),   //quality
     2 => array(1 => 6,  2 => 7,  3 => 8,  4 => 9,  5 => 10),  //value
     3 => array(1 => 11, 2 => 12, 3 => 13, 4 => 14, 5 => 15),  //price 
     4 => array(1 => 16, 2 => 17, 3 => 18, 4 => 19, 5 => 20)   //rating
);*/

//Lets Assume User Chooses Rating based on Rating Attributes called(quality,value,price,rating)
$ratingOptions = array(
            '1' => '1',
            '2' => '7',
            '3' => '13',
            '4' => '19'
);      

foreach ($ratingOptions as $ratingId => $optionIds) 
{     
       $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\Rating")
                     ->setRatingId($ratingId)
                     ->setReviewId($_review->getId())
                     ->addOptionVote($optionIds, $productId);

}
echo  "Latest REVIEW ID ===".$_review->getId()."</br>";     
$_review->aggregate();
echo "Rating has been saved submitted  successfully";

?>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how I store it for guest user?

Comment: Hi @Mayur just keep $customerId=Null for guest user.

Comment: you will get output as shown in this screenshot https://prnt.sc/jcmfm5 as well i updated code please check the same

Comment: review added and i can see it in admin but in frontend its not showing any idea about that.

Comment: please approve the review from admin end check the same in the frontend and let me know

Comment: @NagarajuK, how to update the review?

Comment: @NagarajuK can I add multiple reviews using this approach?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't try. but need to prepare the array and using the loop we can do it. I think

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the code of [Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/99e85cbc45223baa3551e4c534b650c0d2c6358b/app/code/Magento/Review/Controller/Product/Post.php) to see how post data is handled to create a review record.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work for posting approved reviews SQL only:

https://github.com/rajan-kz/Magento-2-SQL-reviews

Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

**HELLO STACK EXCHANGEPHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`estorexl_eu_2021_staging`.`review_detail`, CONSTRAINT `REVIEW_DETAIL_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE SE) in /home/httpd/ebouwmarkt/ebouwmarkt.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91
Stack trace:
#0 /home/httpd/ebouwmarkt/ebouwmarkt.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(91): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 /home/httpd/ebouwmarkt/ebouwmarkt.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(107): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo{closure}()
#2 /home/httpd/ebouwmarkt/ebouwmarkt.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(92): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->tryExecute()
#3 /home/httpd/ebouwmarkt/ebouwmarkt.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/zend in /home/httpd/ebouwmarkt/ebouwmarkt.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 110
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`estorexl_eu_2021_staging`.`review_detail`, CONSTRAINT `REVIEW_DETAIL_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE SE) in /home/httpd/ebouwmarkt/ebouwmarkt.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91
Stack trace:**

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/194939)